# Widget name not shown fully?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

Suppose if my widget name is "This is a very long widget name 4x1" It is not fully displayed in the dialog box where we select home screen widgets. Only some portion of the starting is shown "This is a very lon...." I see this problem in my HTC wildfire S, and not in Samsung Galaxy S. Is this a problem in the device or am I missing something,?

Comment: The Wildfire S has a much smaller screen resolution as a consequence Android downscales everything, so it will elipsize any text which is too long for the layout which it is held in

Comment: Also bear in mind that the app widget selection mechanism is a home screen feature, and so the presentation will vary by home screen implementation. Choose short names. :-)

Comment: Where can i change the names of the app widgets displayed in list? So that i can give a short form name of my app!

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem with the wigdet selector list. The text is to long for the the widget name so it will not display all of the text.